# Button that unloads external JS file

Tags: javascript, button

So I have in my header a JS script like this, that activates reading on my website.

```
<script src='//vws.responsivevoice.com/v/e?key=kukrWmCv'></script>
```

I want to unload the script from the header by pressing a HTML button, but I really do not know how to this. Any help apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an id to your script tag:

```
<script src='//vws.responsivevoice.com/v/e?key=kukrWmCv' id="myScript"></script>
```

Call a function on click of the button and have the below code in your function

```
var yourScript = document.createElementById('myScript');

 yourScript.setAttribute('src','');
```